# Cubic polynomial without $x^1$

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I factorized this equation

$4x^3+6x^2-1=0$

I think it's harder to factorize when the $x$ (degree one) doesn't exist here.
So, this is what I did now:

$2x^2(2x+3)-1=0$

But the factorized equation looks like this:
$(2x+1)(2x^2+2x-1)=0$

What happens in between these last steps?

I did synthetic division for the root $-1/2$, but how do I get the other two roots?

Comment: Even though your first step is valid, it is not the proper step toward a full factorization.  Instead, for such a cubic write down:  $(a x + b)(c x^2 + d x + e)$ and solve for the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I think you are looking for the following [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Based on it, we find out that $-1/2$ is a rational root.

Taking advantage of the knowledge of such solution, we can factor the given polynomial as next:
\begin{align*}
4x^{3} + 6x^{2} - 1 = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (4x^{3} + 2x^{2}) + (4x^{2} - 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2x^{2}(2x + 1) + (2x + 1)(2x - 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2x^{2} + 2x - 1)(2x + 1) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

as $0$ is not a root, we lose nothing by writing $x= \frac{1}{t},$   then multiplying the result by $ \; \; - t^3 \; . \; \; $
$$  t^3 - 6t -4  $$
If it factors, there is a rational root, and this $t$  value must be an integer that divides $4,$  so $\pm 1 , \; \pm 2 \; , \; \pm 4  $

Comment: One might just as well use the rational root theorem on the original polynomial. You don't need to go through such a transformation step.

Answer (score 0):

To get the other two roots, it is possible to use the quadratic equation on $2x^{2} + 2x - 1$ by assigning the polynomial to $0$. Or, as stated by other users, it is possible to just use the Rational Root Theorem since the original polynomial does not have that many terms.